# PHP: Escape RegEx pattern to prevent being applied?

Tags: php, regex, escaping

Is there a PHP function that can escape RegEx patterns to prevent them from being applied when used inside another RegEx pattern?

I am looking for something along the lines of the C# [`Regex.Escape()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) function.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

[`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote) is what you are looking for:

> ### Description
>
> ```
> string preg_quote ( string $str [, string $delimiter = NULL ] )
> ```
>
> **preg_quote()** takes **`str`**  and puts a
>   backslash in front of every character
>   that is part of the regular expression
>   syntax. This is useful if you have a
>   run-time string that you need to match
>   in some text and the string may
>   contain special regex characters.
>
> The special regular expression
>   characters are: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`
>
> ### Parameters
>
> #### str
>
> The input string.
>
> #### delimiter
>
> If the optional delimiter is specified, it will also be escaped. This is useful for escaping the delimiter that is required by the PCRE functions. The / is the most commonly used delimiter.

Importantly, note that if the `$delimiter` argument is not specified, the [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) - the character used to enclose your regex, commonly a forward slash (`/`) - will not be escaped. You will usually want to pass whatever delimiter you are using with your regex as the `$delimiter` argument.

#### Example - using `preg_match` to find occurrences of a given URL surrounded by whitespace:

```
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest';

// preg_quote escapes the dot, question mark and equals sign in the URL (by
// default) as well as all the forward slashes (because we pass '/' as the
// $delimiter argument).
$escapedUrl = preg_quote($url, '/');

// We enclose our regex in '/' characters here - the same delimiter we passed
// to preg_quote
$regex = '/\s' . $escapedUrl . '\s/';
// $regex is now:  /\shttp\:\/\/stackoverflow\.com\/questions\?sort\=newest\s/

$haystack = "Bla bla http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest bla bla";
preg_match($regex, $haystack, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
// array(1) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(48) " http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest "
// }
```

Comment: One additional remark to [@TomHaigh](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1531471/89771) answer, if you don't specify the second `$delimiter` argument to `preg_quote()` **[it won't escape any delimiter](http://codepad.org/6mRuajog)**, not even the "default" (or the most common) `/`.

Comment: I've added a whole bunch of stuff to this answer - the note brought up by @AlixAxel about the importance of the `$delimiter` argument, the description of that argument from the docs, a clarification for the confused about exactly what it means, and a heavily commented example showing `preg_quote` being used in the simplest case I could come up with where it's actually being used to programatically form a regex and put it into another `preg_*` function (because otherwise, what's the point?). Feel free to rollback if you don't like the change.

Comment: @AlixAxel The preg_quote() function escapes some delimiters including = : < and >. See my article: https://www.abareplace.com/blog/escape-regexp/

Answer (score 2):

It would be much safer to use [Prepared Patterns](https://t-regx.com/docs/handling-user-input) from [T-Regx](https://t-regx.com) (i'm the author of the library):

```
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest';

$pattern = Pattern::inject('\s@\s', [$url]);
                                    // ↑ $url is quoted
```

then perform normal match:

```
$haystack = "Bla bla http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest bla bla";

$matcher = pattern->match($haystack);
foreach ($matcher as $match) {
}
```

you can even use it with `preg_match()`:

```
preg_match($pattern, 'foo', $matches);
```

Comment: Can you please explain, why it should be "safer" to pull in another library, if a standard PHP does the job?

Comment: Vanilla PHP don't work for all cases. For example string `"\\"` will cause error if it's the last character.

Comment: This is the second answer I've seen of yours in a day mentioning this library, and I realise now it's because it's your own. SO policy requires that you make any association clear in your answer when recommending your own tools.

Comment: @HashimAziz Thanks for notising, I posted the answer 4 year ago right after I created the lib. I was young and silly, accept my apology.