# Escaping string for use in regular expression

Tags: php, regex, escaping, pcre

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a PHP function that can escape regex patterns before they are applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531456/is-there-a-php-function-that-can-escape-regex-patterns-before-they-are-applied)

I want to use a string stored in a variable in a regular expression. What's the best way (in PHP) to escape a string for use in a (PCRE) regular expression?

For example,

```
$text = 'm/z';  // this is the text I want to use as part of my regular expression
$text_regexp = '#' . $text . '#i';  // this is my regular expression
```

Would give

```
$text_regexp = '#m/z#i';
```

But I would want the following regular expression:

```
$text_regexp = '#m\/z#i';
```

This is a contrived example, but I wanted to illustrate the point simply.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

From the manual:

> puts a backslash in front of every
>   character that is part of the regular
>   expression syntax

You can also pass the delimiter as the second parameter and it will also be escaped. However, if you're using `#` as your delimiter, then there's no need to escape `/`

Comment: For generalizations, see also [this complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486/287948).

Answer (score 11):

You must use the [`preg_quote` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php):

> `preg_quote ( string $str [, string $delimiter = NULL ] )`

Example of a `$keyword` that must match as a whole word:

```php
$pattern = '/\b' . preg_quote($keyword, '/') . '\b/';
```

Comment: This is **THE ANSWER**!

Answer (score 5):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531456/is-there-a-php-function-that-can-escape-regex-patterns-before-they-are-applied). You can use preg_quote();.

Answer (score 5):

All these answers are correct, only the metachars need to be escaped. 
Its kind of too bad that php doesen't have a regex operator like preg_match([operator]/$var/) so the delimeters could be the quoting agent. This way delimeter wouldn't have to be quoted in an external $var. (Perl has this with  m//,s/// or =~ operators)

The preg_quote is a nice way to do this, unfortunately, sometimes you want to match literal '\char' without it being escaped to '\char' for instance, and escape the rest. Not many choices with preg_quote().

You could literally set up your own php functions that does quoting of metachars (or take off a quote after preg_quote() ).

like a replace all `/([{}\[\]()^\$.|*+?\\<>$delim])/` with `\\$1` or something. Set the $delim, and/or take out possibly the escape or any other metachars you don't want escaped.

Just my $.02

Comment: You can use `quotemeta()` function to escape meta characters. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quotemeta.php