# Remove duplicates of certain characters from string

Tags: php

How could I remove duplicates of characters found in array `$a` from string `$b` only if they are found next to each other?

```
$a = array("a","b","c");
$b = "aabcccdef";
```

Output should be

```
abcdef
```

Characters can be found with a regex but I have no idea how to detect if the characters are next to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace( array('/a+/','/b+/','/c+/'),array('a','b','c',), $b );
```

Another way pretty more elaborate could be:

```
preg_replace_callback('/(\w+)/', function ($matches) use ($a) {

   if ( in_array($matches[1][0],$a) )  //> if you need UTF-8 working use mb_substr here
    return $matches[1][0];

},$b);

//> both untested
```

Another way, old way (that could be a bit faster on few chars string):

```
$c = '';
$cache = false;
for ($i=0;$i<strlen($b);$i++) {
  $char = $b[$i];

  if ($char !== $cache || !in_array($char,$a)) 
   $c .= $char;

  $cache=$char;
}
echo $c;
```

Comment: Fantastic, though I have to admit I'm a bit puzzled by the first array.

Comment: to create the first array you can do a foreach and add / +/ to each value, or just use the second option

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
$expression = join('|', $a);
$b = preg_replace('/(' . $expression . ')\1+/', '$1', $b);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/gLTydxlG)

Explanation:

The generated expression will look like `(a|b)\1+`, where `a|b` matches either `a` or `b`. `\1` matches whatever was matched by the first capture group `(a|b)`. This is how you can match a set of repeating characters. The match then gets replaced by the content of the capture group (`$1`).

This would not only work with single characters but with any substrings.

If the strings can contain special regular expression characters, you should [escape those characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531456/is-there-a-php-function-that-can-escape-regex-patterns-before-they-are-applied) first (`array_map('preg_quote', $a)` should work just fine).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$b = 'aabcccdef';
$c = '';
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($b); $i++) {
    if(in_array($b[$i], $a) && (substr($c, -1) === $b[$i])) {
        continue;
    }
    $c .= $b[$i];
}
echo $c;
```