# How to remove duplicates of a specific character in string with PHP

Tags: php, string, duplicates, character

Let's say i have the string `$urlname = "pine-tree-tshirt--green-xs"`

I want my result to be `$urlname = "pine-tree-tshirt-green-xs"`

I **don't** want to remove all duplicates characters (for example tree, the e should be duplicated here), only the - character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates of certain characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350851/remove-duplicates-of-certain-characters-from-string)

Comment: `str_replace("--","-",$urlname);`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile thanks, it is a duplicate, and I found there the answer
$characterwanted = array("-");
$expression = join('|', $characterwanted);
$result = preg_replace('/(' . $expression . ')\1+/', '$1', $urlname);