# PHP preg_replace is not matching entire pattern

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I'm stuck trying to get the PHP preg_replace to work properly.  I want to find all matches of a pattern and replace them with a string.  But, for some reason, it's finding only partial matches and replacing all of them.  I'm trying to remove the "password" from every line of a text file. The password is always at the end of each line, contains 4 to 8 alpha-numeric characters, and always follows two pipe characters.

Example:

```
$data = 'A00000001|A00000001|FirstName|LastName|email@address|Role||password'.PHP_EOL;
$data .= 'B00000002|B00000002|FirstName|LastName|email@address|Role||password'.PHP_EOL;
$delim = '|';

$newData = preg_replace("/".$delim.$delim."[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,8}/", $delim.$delim, $data);
echo $newData;
```

Output:

> ||||||1|||||||||1|||||||||e||||||||||||e||m||a||i||l||@||a||d||d||r||e||s||s|||||R||o||l||e||||||||||||
>   ||||||2|||||||||2|||||||||e||||||||||||e||m||a||i||l||@||a||d||d||r||e||s||s|||||R||o||l||e||||||||||||
>   ||

I've tried many variations with different groupings using parenthesis, putting back to back `[a-zA-Z0-9]` patterns instead of {#}.  I've tried adding line start `^` and end `$` to my pattern.  I'm stuck.  I know this will end up being something simple to that I'm just overlooking.  That's why I need some fresh eyes on this.

Comment: Relevant info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531456/is-there-a-php-function-that-can-escape-regex-patterns-before-they-are-applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can just escape your delimiters.

```
$newData = preg_replace('/\'.$delim.'\'.$delim.'[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,8}/', $delim.$delim, $data);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Although, I had to use double escapes with my double-quoted code: `$newData = preg_replace("/\\".$delim."\\".$delim."[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,8}/", $delim.$delim, $data);`

Answer (score 3):

You should use this regex

```
/(?<=\|\|)[a-zA-Z]{4,8}$/
```

You need to escape `|` since it represents OR in regex

`$` marks the end of string

`(?<=\|\|)` is a [zero width lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: When I used your regex pattern, it only removed the "password" in the 2nd line.  I'm assuming this is due to the lookbehind portion. You're correct about escaping the pipe.  I knew it would be something simple.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to remove the "password" from every line of a text file.

In this case, anchor the regex after properly escaping your delimiter. Assuming the delim shouldn't be kept either, you could use:

```
preg_replace('/\|.*?$/', '', $data);
```

If it should, use a look-behind or:

```
preg_replace('/\|.*?$/', '|', $data);
```

---

On a separate note: this looks like an SQL dump or a CSV file. If so, consider using whichever variation of `COPY ... DELIMITER ...` your RDBMS offers instead:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

You could then create a temporary table, import, drop the column, do whatever else you need to do, and populate the final tables as needed once you're done.

Comment: Thanks Denis.  I fixed it by escaping the pipe char.  This is manipulating a csv file that I don't have control over how it's being made.  This is a temporary fix until it can be fixed properly on the other party's side.