# Passing parameters to SQL regular expressions

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I was wondering if it is possible to pass parameters to regular expressions as if they were literal strings in the MySQL REGEXP function. What I would like to do is the following:

```
SELECT ? REGEXP CONCAT('string', ?, 'string')
```

Now when I pass a dot (".") to the second parameter, it will automatically match any character, as expected. This means that strings like "stringastring" and "stringbstring"  match the pattern. I wondered if it is possible to match the literal dot only, so as to only match "string.string" in this case. Is there a way to do such a thing with a MySQL regular expression, that does not involve explicitly escaping the parameter (which defeats the purpose of passing parameters in this first place)?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting brackets, as in:

```
SELECT ? REGEXP CONCAT('string', '[.]', 'string')
```

See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3059/1

Comment: Quite frankly this doesn't answer the question. The hack isn't applicable either, because I don't know the length of the parameter I am going to pass.

Comment: I don't think you can use regular expressions without explicitly escaping the special character. See the link that I put.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT ? REGEXP CONCAT('string', REPLACE(?, '.', '[.]'), 'string')
```

using the REPLACE function, any dot is always escaped to [.], but all others special characters are passed literally.

Comment: No I intend to pass parameters to the regular expression for it to interpet them as literals. If that dot were a ^ or a series of characters.. hacks such as the one you suggest don't apply.

Comment: @user2180613 but why you need a regular expressions and not just a LIKE or a = ?

Comment: Well because the use case requires a regular expression? And it's a quite complicated one too.

Comment: @user2180613 okay so the two strings are two regular expressions, it's just the parameter that has to be matched literally?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using PHP and looking for answer related to this I found an answer related to this in stackover [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531456/is-there-a-php-function-that-can-escape-regex-patterns-before-they-are-applied), though not directly for MySQL queries. The idea is to use preg_quote() to escape regexp meta characters. But in your case you have to apply it twice to your parameter.

`$param = preg_quote(preg_quote($param))`

Then

`SELECT ? REGEXP CONCAT('string', $param, 'string')`

Read this [article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) and the comments to find out more