# escape special character from string in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

we are trying to escape some special character from our string please tell me the function that we have to use
e.g. HTC Desire 210 – White
In this example we escape -(hyphen) special character.
In above example we have lot of product name with different different special character that we escape it.
thanks for your co-operation.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post your attempts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all special characters from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string)

Answer (score 5):

Pass string in this function.

```
function clean($string){
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces spaces with hyphens.
   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}
```

For more info, check this [Remove Special Character - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

The mysqli_real_escape_string() function escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement.

**Syntax:**

```
mysqli_real_escape_string(connection,escapestring);
```

**Example** Escape special characters in a string:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['age']);

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$age')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**connection**  Required. Specifies the MySQL connection to use

**escapestring**    Required. The string to be escaped. Characters encoded are NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z.

Comment: Why would you encourage anyone to use this function in the new code? It doesn't even answer the question OP has.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), for example ;

```
str_replace(array(':', '-', '/', '*'), '', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to escape characters that would break a regex / PCRE function (e.g., `preg_match()`) if not escaped, you can use [preg_quote()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

For example, let's say your needle and haystack are:

```
$needle   = "needle(";
$haystack = "ibivfdubdvwbneedle(cihbdhcbds";
```

The following `preg_match()` will throw a warning:

```
var_dump(preg_match("/" . $needle . "/", $haystack)); -----> WARNING preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 7 on line number 9 bool(false)
```

because a left parenthesis is a character used in regular expression syntax. However, if you use `preg_quote()` on the needle, the left parenthesis will be escaped and the regex check will execute:

```
var_dump(preg_match("/" . preg_quote($needle) . "/", $haystack)); ----> int(1)
```

More discussion about `preg_quote()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531456/is-there-a-php-function-that-can-escape-regex-patterns-before-they-are-applied).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addcslashes()`.

Returns a string with backslashes before characters that are given in second parameter

```
<?php
echo addcslashes("union [", '+,-,[,]');
// output: union \[
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the system function $city = $mysqli->real_escape_string($city);

here : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the string for database's **SQL operation** then You can escape special characters in mysqli using function [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Syntax:

> mysqli_real_escape_string(connection,escapestring);

Example:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$your_string = 'string "hi" ';
$escaped_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $your_string);
$sql = 'select * from tablename where fields like "%'.$escaped_string. '%" ';
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//here you can iterate over result array for displaying result

?>
```

you can use **[addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) to escape the string, which Returns a string with backslashes added before characters like:**

- single quote (')
- double quote (")
- backslash (\)
- NUL (the NUL byte)

But `addslashes()` has some vulnerabilities to sql injections for detail see the answer of this question [Examples of SQL Injections through addslashes()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860954/examples-of-sql-injections-through-addslashes), so better to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function if you are doing database operations.

Or if you want to **escape characters for regular expressions** then you can use
[preg_quote ( string $str [, string $delimiter = NULL ] )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), which **puts a backslash in front of every character that is part of the regular expression** syntax.
regular expression characters are: **. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -**

**Note:** But be careful `preg_quote()` will not escape `single(')` or `double quote(")`.

Comment: Haritsinh Gohil You can escape string using mysqli_real_escape_string() function but it not built for this purpose. It is build to escape string before sending it off to MySQL server. (Plus you can't escape string directly; you would need a link connection before that).

Comment: @AdeelRazaAzeemi you are right, just updated the answer, thanks