# How to escape regex special characters from array using php to use in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have an array that also contains regex special characters in its some values, I want to `implode()` it so that special characters in its some values escape using `preg_quote()`

Here is what I tried

```
$arr = array("+1", "1+4"); 
echo implode("|", $arr);
```

I want escaped output like this

```
\+1|1\+4|
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: You did not research this, as any reasonable search on the internet would have pointed you to the right method.

Comment: There is another way too `"\Q" . implode("\E|\Q", $arr) . "\E"`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531456/is-there-a-php-function-that-can-escape-regex-patterns-before-they-are-applied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`array_map()`](https://secure.php.net/array_map) with [`preg_quote()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) like this :

```
$arr = array("+1", "1+4"); 
echo implode("|", array_map('preg_quote', $arr));
```

Outputs :

```
\+1|1\+4
```

---

To get the final pipe :

```
$arr = array("+1", "1+4" , ""); 
echo implode("|", array_map('preg_quote', $arr)) ;
// Or
$arr = array("+1", "1+4"); 
echo implode("|", array_map('preg_quote', $arr)) . "|" ;
```

Outputs :

```
\+1|1\+4|
```