# How to use PHP preg_match delimiter pattern in this code?

Tags: php, preg-match

After reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705399/warning-preg-replace-unknown-modifier) and after trying [preg_quote](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), I understand the error and I understand that I must use delimiters.

The problem is one of the delimiter is a forward slash which is also part of the string that I'm trying to compare. I do not understand how to fix my problem. Where do I put the delimiters in my code?

I'm using preg_match to identify a given product with the product name as follow :

```
if (preg_match("/\b$productcolor\b/i", "$searchProductName")) { 

//do something
}
```

This works well if the product name looks like this :

```
$searchProductName = Yupoong 6606 Retro Trucker Cap (Red);//$_POST
$productcolor = 'Red';//$_POST
```

`Preg_match` returns unknown modifier if there is a forward slash in the name like this :

```
$searchProductName = Yupoong 6606 Retro Trucker Cap (Rust Orange/ Khaki);//$_POST
$productcolor = 'Rust Orange/ Khaki';//$_POST
```

I'm trying to get over that problem by eliminating the forward slash like this :

```
$productColor = str_replace('/', ' ', $productcolor);
```

This will return a string like this `Rust Orange Khaki`. But removing the forward slash makes `preg_match` not matching the color in the name.

How can I solve this problem? Mind you, NOT all products have a forward slash in their name. Some have single colors.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php Use a different delimeter.

Comment: Either as already mentioned change the delimiter or escape the regex (passing in the delimiter your using - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531456/is-there-a-php-function-that-can-escape-regex-patterns-before-they-are-applied)

Comment: Please take a look at Toto answer (that perfectly answers your question) and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

[`preg_quote`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-quote.php) is your friend. It escapes special characters.

```
if (preg_match("/\b" . preg_quote($productcolor, "/") . "\b/i", $searchProductName)) { 
    //do something
}
```

Comment: If I were you, I will add the delimiter as second parameter of `preg_quote`.